# Json to CSV select second level columns

Tags: powershell

I have a json in the below format, where some columns are at 2nd level. I want to the column at the second level to be at the first level in CSV

```
{
  "ApiKey": "123",
  "BasicDetails": {
    "ClientID": "1234",
    "CompanyName": "C1",
    "ContactName": "",
    "EmailAddress": "",
    "Country": "United Kingdom",
    "TimeZone": "(GMT+00:00)"
  }}
```

Required Output is:

```
APIKey, ClientID, CompanyName, ContactName, EmailAddress,Country,Timezone
123,1234,C1,,,United Kingdom,(GMT+00:00)
```

I have tried:

```
(GET-Content F:/my.json -RAW | ConvertFrom-Json)|Select Columns|Export-CSV F:/my.csv
```

**EDIT**
Actual Json:
{

```
    "ApiKey": "123",
      "BasicDetails": {
        "ClientID": "1234",
        "CompanyName": "C1",
        "ContactName": "",
        "EmailAddress": "",
        "Country": "United Kingdom",
        "TimeZone": "(GMT+00:00)"
      }
    "BillingDetails": {
    "CurrentTier": "0 - 500",
    "CurrentMonthlyRate": 9.0000,
    "MarkupPercentage": 0,
    "MonthlyScheme": "Basic",
    "Currency": "USD",
    "ClientPays": false
  }}
```

I need Belling Detail columns, Basic Details column and API key at one level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for a all JSON files with a depth of two (which you requested):

```
$tempObject = @{}

(GET-Content F:/my.json -RAW | convertfrom-json).PsObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.TypeNameOfValue -eq 'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject')
    {
        $_.Value.PsObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
            $tempObject  += @{$_.Name = $_.Value}
        }        
    }
    else
    {
        $tempObject  += @{$_.Name = $_.Value}
    }
} 
[PsCustomObject]$tempObject | Export-CSV F:/my.csv
```

Comment: thanks for responding. I have billing details as well with basic details. I have edited my question, could you you look at the json and suggest

Comment: I edited my answer. It is generic and should work for all JSON files. Give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Tricky question. Depends very much if you are looking for a solution for your specific case or a more general approach.

For the first, go with Martin Brandl's answer.

Else, there is also `ConvertTo-FlatObject`:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ConvertTo-FlatObject-396a6e0a